# How to edit UITableViewCell frame position programmatically

Tags: objective-c

I need to edit the position of an `UITableViewCell` programmatically, this is the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"leftMenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }


    if([[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue] == 1)
    {

        CGRect frame = cell.textLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x= 30;
        cell.textLabel.frame= frame;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Using breakpoints I can see that the `if` condition works but the code to edit the frame position does nothing. Is it possible to edit the position like this or i'll have to subclass `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: subclass the tablecell and in layout subviews method, change the cell frame. See if it works or not!!

Comment: @Mr.T the problem is that I have 2 type of cells, 0 is a top level cell and 1 is a child cell, what i'm doing is a slide menu with cells containing sub-cells so I need to edit the position only of the sub-cells and if I do it in the layout subviews method i'll edit the position of every cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create 2 subclasses of UITableViewCell with 2 different identifiers depending on the one you want to display if they are different.

You could customize frame in each subclass as you want and it will be easier for you to work with it

Comment: I was thinking the same but then how can I know which one should I initialize? Because the method cellForRowAtIndexPath requires me to declare an UITableViewCell but if I don't know if it's a parent or child cell I can't initialize the correct subclass

Comment: What I dont understand is that if you have child cells into a parent cell, Maybe you have a custom UITableViewCell in which you initialize your child cells ?

Comment: no I still haven't subclassed anything, what I did in order to achieve the parent --> child effect was using the cell.indentationLevel, then based on the indentationLevel (0, 1) I know which ones are parents and childs. On click of a parent I display all of it's child and On click of a child I do whatever I want (for example push to another view)

Comment: ok yeah I just understood your solution, before declaring the UITableViewCell I check the level of the cell and then I initialize the correct one, Sorry it took me so long but i'm pretty tired :P thank you!